# Why declaring an arrray of strings with a pointer? What really happens when doing it?

Tags: c

In C, why we are declaring arrays that has strings using

`char* arr[] = {"PYTHON","JAVA","RUBY","C++"};`

instead of

`char arr[] = {"PYTHON","JAVA","RUBY","C++"};`

Why it returns error "excess elements in char array initializer" and what does it means? Also what really happens underneath the first one?

Comment: For one, `char arr[] = {"PYTHON","JAVA","RUBY","C++"};` certainly isn't doing what you think it is. If you have a question about a warning or error, *always* post the error verbatim [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59057575/edit), and describe what part(s) of it you find confusing.

Comment: Because strings are actually arrays in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fundamentally, a string in C is an array of `char`.

Because of the correspondence between arrays and pointers in C, it is very common and very convenient to refer to an array using a pointer to its first element.

So although strings are fundamentally arrays of `char`, it is very common to refer to them using pointers to `char`.

So `char *arr[]` (which has type "array of pointer to `char`") is a good way to implement an array of strings.

You can't write

```
char arr[] = {"PYTHON", "JAVA", "RUBY", "C++"};
```

because it's a type mismatch (and correspondingly meaningless).  If you declare an array of `char`, the initializer for it must be characters.  So you could do

```
char arr[] = { 'P', 'Y', 'T', 'H', 'O', 'N' };
```

Or, as a special shortcut, you could do

```
char arr[] = "PYTHON";
```

where the initializer is a *single* string literal.  This string literal is an array of `char`, so it's a fine initializer for `arr` which is an array of `char`.  But there's no direct way to pack multiple strings (as in your original question) into a single array of `char`.

Of course, there's one more issue, and that's null termination.  More precisely, a string in C is a *null terminated* array of `char`.  So the "special shortcut"

```
char arr[] = "PYTHON";
```

is actually equivalent to

```
char arr[] = { 'P', 'Y', 'T', 'H', 'O', 'N', '\0' };
```